# Should employees with head injuries be allowed to post on meta?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2013, fun

While yodeling to myself quietly in our warehouse today, a pallet full of mugs came crashing down on my head, and gave me a <strike>concussion</strike> idea. First, it's very unlucky to go yodeling around on a skate board in a dark warehouse, and second, we could really use a short creative writing contest.

Fortunately, we didn't make any hard hats this year, so my head injury is your gain.

#### The Objective

Write a short, humorous and fictional story about *using* a Stack Exchange site that mentions:

- At least **two** of the current [Winter Bash](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com) hats, by exact name (secret hats that have shown up on at least one profile are okay too).
- At least **one** of the current Winter Bash hat criteria
- At least **one** [Stack Exchange site](https://stackexchange.com/sites#oldest) that is in public beta or beyond
- Tim Post's **head** (*has to be only his head*), yodeling, or both

#### What do I get?

*Authors of the top three entries will receive:*

- Stack Overflow Mug
- Stack Exchange [Nalgene](http://nalgene.com/) Water Bottle
- Stack Overflow T-shirt
- Assorted stickers and secret surprises

*Two runners-up will receive:*

- Stack Overflow T-shirt
- Assorted stickers and secret surprises

#### How do I win?

Have the highest, second highest or third highest up-vote count on your entry. Down votes do not affect scoring. Be original & creative, and be funny.

#### What are the rules?

- Employees are welcome to participate, but entries by employees will not be counted. Ya'll get this stuff by walking upstairs and grabbing it or asking me to send it to you.
- Limit two entries per user
- Entries must not exceed 1024 characters (not including markdown formatting characters) to be eligible.
- Void where prohibited, or if management shuts it down
- Entries must be received by 20:00 UTC on Friday, December 20, 2013.
- In case of a tie for any prize, all entries of the same score will be awarded the prize.

These only come around once a year, so make it count :) Good luck!

## Winners!

Winning entries:

- Esoteric Screen Name (87) (Best use of my head, ever, seriously.)
- Generic Holiday Name (25)
- Retailcoder (22)

Runners-up:

- Fredley (15)
- rlemon (13)

Honorable mention (will get a T-shirt):

- qwertynl (12)

Thank you to all that participated, and made this contest fun! There will be one more before the end of Winter Bash, and some mini contests in chat to look forward to. I will be contacting the winners early next week to get your size, shipping info and preferences.

Stay tuned, and thanks again!

Comment: @rene Let's keep this one to English, but I promise to look into running something like this on the new Portuguese site with Gabe's help (and blessing).

Comment: @TinyTim Sorry, I meant do winners get a new secret hat too?

Comment: At least it wasn't [mercury-tainted cigarettes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144601/reversing-a-year-long-ban-on-meta-stack-overflow/144680#144680) again.

Comment: Can I just post a bunch of funny imaeg instead?  I mean, really funny.  Good stuff.

Comment: @Won't You can make an illustrated story, sure, but there's got to be an actual story that meets the criteria there for it to be considered.

Comment: @TinyTim: Hmmm, story in image format... Mulling.

Comment: 1024 chars including Markdown syntax?

Comment: @Seth I can not confirm or deny the triggering of a secret hat for the winners of this contest.

Comment: @fredley Excluding markdown, rendered formatted text is considered. I'll edit for clarity, thanks.

Comment: @TinyTim Are we supposed to **embolden** all of our references?

Comment: @qwertynl Your discretion, not a requirement

Comment: @qwertynl - I started that trend, because I wasn't sure if anyone would know Aviation was in Beta.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Aviation is **not** in PUBLIC beta. Doesn't count :-P

Comment: _"all entries of the same score will be awarded the prize."_ So if there is a tie, all posts with a score of 1 will win the prize? :]

Comment: Once a year? But we had those prizes [a month ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208393/152859)... not that I complain though. ;)

Comment: I don't understand. Why did a pallet full of mugs yodel to yourself? Dangling modifier is dangling. No wonder it came crashing down.

Comment: You do realise that after too many concussions comes senility and a requirement for adult diapers?

Comment: Just to avoid disappointment, does your offer also work for ... *foreigners*? (i.e., people you have to pay international postage for)

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I was thinking about it, but fulfilling the requirements *and* making it a haiku seems impossible.

Comment: @FEichinger I have succeeded in creating a haiku that meets the objectives and requirements.  [Here it is, enjoy!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212587/200866)

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Have all the upvotes, good Sir! All the upvotes!

Answer (score 85):

'Twas the night before Christmas, and wearing my Full House,
I was on StackOverflow, clicking my mouse.
I edited ten questions with care,
In hopes that answers soon would be there.

Answers on "how to parse html" filled me with dreads;
No doubt visions of precious repz danced in users' heads.
Downvoting the questions, I in my cap,
Exclaimed out loud, "Hey, what is this crap?"

When out on the lawn there arose such a yodel,
"YOU CAN’T PARSE HTML WITH REGEX, NOT EVEN WITH JS.NODAL!"
Away to the window I flew like a flash,
Slammed shut the shutters and threw down the sash.

From my chimney came a voice of timbre low,
Echoing dark and ominous cries of "Ho Ho Ho".
When, what to my wondering eyes should appear,
But Tim Post's head in a Santa hat, how queer!

His mouth opened and oozed black goo quite thick,
I knew in a moment this was no St. Nick.
My hair on end, Oh the Horror, I was struck lame;
To hear the head forebodingly proclaim:
M̷̶͚͉̰̺̻̰̘̲̗o̴̱̰̫̬͍̩̯ͅr̢̪̰͢ẹ̢̯̗̮̞͍͢ ̡̢̳̣̲͠r̶̡̻̹̹̞̜̟͕̙̝a̢̩̬̱̜̮̺̟̰ͅp̡͕̭͓̖͎͍i̶̹̭ḑ͓͚͓͟ ̬̀͟t̰̬̟̤͇̫͝h̵̼̞͚̗̹̼͟a̛͙̰͙̘͍̱͙̕͟n̵̹̜̖̟͡ ̡̼̱̝̲̯e̴̙̼̜͈̖͉̥ͅá̶͖̖̺g̜͙l̶̛̫̤̘̙̝͈̻͢e̳̱̻̪̟͞s̵̩̲̹̺̝̰͉͈͢ ̡̩͍̜̟̯̳h̰̱e̛̩̥͍̦͘͜ͅ ̡̘͓̦̝̤̬͓͡͞c̷̥̩̝̪̟̦ò͖̝̥̩͓͎̫̩͜m͚̬̟͟e̼̤̹̠̰͠s̬̦
̩̜̜̣̳́
̫̺̖͖̬̣͖O͈̳̦̱̯͕Ņ̶̟̩͖̖͔͙̜̩͟ ̡͕̜͓̣͓͓̮̱͘͠Z͙͉̳͟A̞̦̳͠L͍̱̱G̶̴̛͎͖O̴̧̡̱̞͇̹͎̙̯͉

[image: Also somehow the walls disappeared.]

Comment: I take my hat off to you, this is excellent.

Comment: Nice homage to @bobince's [classic HTML/Regex answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/242).

Comment: @fredley, it would seem your hat is still on sir.

Comment: This is now a family heirloom.

Answer (score 24):

Forty votes in a day, on Stack Overflow,
was leaving me winded, tired and slow.

A Boater, no more, I thought to appear,
when a horrible sound came forth to my ear.

A yodel, it's called, in mountainous lands,
often heard solo (sometimes in a band).

Away from my desk I swiftly did move,
I saw what I could not, *would not* approve.

"Oh the Horror!" I cried, fraught with dismay,
three shiny diamonds, heading this way.

t'was Anna, Tim Post, and Shog shortly after,
but *only their heads*, eyes full of laughter.

I pleaded for mercy, judging them kind,
but all I received was a [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

**...**

My posts are all gone now, lost to the stack.
I just don't see how I'll *ever* bounce back.

I stumble through days, *weeks*, in a daze,
hoping for upvotes or even just praise.

I no longer review, or edit a post,
for I've *seen* their fury, closer than most.

The moral, you ask? Well, it's quite clear.
When you see a diamond, see it with fear.

Remember my story, remember it true.
One day, who knows? It could happen to you.

Comment: [Text without markdown](http://pastebin.com/ZK0E7UNS), 1024 characters.

Answer (score 19):

#### A long time ago, in a galaxy far, far away...

There was this **Bounty Hunter** that travelled the Stack Exchange world like a **Chuck Yeager**, always the *fastest gun in the west*, always on time, always right, never afraid to **steal a checkmark**.

Most of his posts managed to get **500 views in 2 days**, but as an **early user** he didn't care for those anymore, all that mattered was the bounty on **Tim Post's head**.

**Oh the horror**, when he found Tim he was **yodeling** with his **Sock Puppet** in one of the SE Chatrooms, where a **Conspiracy Theorist** had mentioned there would be a delay of *6 to 8 weeks* to set up a Data Explorer that **Code Review** enthusiasts could use to analyze their site's data.

Comment: I think I might have mixed-up Tims... bah, it's fictional right?

Comment: I feel compelled to give this an up vote, for meta-meta reasons.

Answer (score 12):

"Your hat, give it to me!" whispered balpha, urgently. "But.." I replied, not wanting to forfeit my headgear.

It had been a treacherous quest into the depths of Area51 to find a new site to explore. After many wrong turns I'd ended up at Pets, tired but determined.

Using what little knowledge I had of 'pets', I tried to ask a question. Success! I'd got an upvote: *Hello World* was mine. Now only hours later at the annual SE yodelling competition, I was being asked to give it up.

"If I don't get it I can't fix this bug!". "No" I said, firmly. "Unless.."
"Unless what?"
"If you gave me *With great power...*"
"Ok, but you'd better give up that diamond once this whole hattening is over"
"Deal. What's the bug anyway?"
"At midnight on NYE, every user would get all hats — SE would collapse into anarchy. Can you imagine a world where everyone was equal?"

Understanding, I removed the mac from my cranium, and he pushed the fix. I relaxed in my seat. Tim Post's dismembered head was on, and actually doing quite well.

Comment: I make this 1024 characters *exactly*.

Comment: Haha **great** jorb :-)

Comment: Please be advised that legitimate Stack Exchange representatives never ask for your hat or other headgear. If you receive such a request, delete it immediately, and be sure to keep you Anti-Hateater program up-to-date.

Answer (score 9):

'Twas [the season of Tims](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132562/150235), when all through the warehouse by Meta,
An employee was yodelling (though his skills were quite beta).
The swag was stacked quite high as if without care,
And the echoing song made it crash down on Tim Post's hair.

"Oh the Horror!" he exclaimed, as 20 hats tumbled down,
"This is not how I wanted to Make it Rain", he said with a frown.
His head aching like too much time spent on Homebrewing,
He vowed to get up – This would not be his undoing.

"Luckily Winter is Coming" he thought to himself,
Using one hand for balance and the other on a shelf.
He pulled himself up and grabbed ice from outside,
Pressed it to his head and gave thanks he hadn't died.

"With Great Power..." he grumbled as he returned for the swag,
Picking up an Old Hat and Sock Puppet to stuff in his bag.
That was that – though he'd rather have hit the rep cap or relaxed with a beer,
Despite the accident this was certainly still his favorite time of year.

Comment: 1054 Characters. Sorry, I am a stickler :-P

Comment: Alright, that should do it. :P

Comment: Yay! Good job @Tim :-)

Answer (score 9):

**Official Entry (within character limit) tl;dr; version**

This year during WinterBash
Stack Overflow sent to me

Twelve Oh the Horrors,
Eleven Chuck Yeagers,
Ten Bounty Hunters,
Nine Sock Puppets,
Eight Lonesome Cowboys,
Seven Frosties the Snowman,
Six RoboCops,
Five Defenders of the Realm,
Four Archeologists,
Johnny Three-Hats,
Two Marauders,
Tim Post's head and R-E-S-P-E-C-T for hitting the rep cap

---

**Unofficial extended version (over character limit)**

On the first day of WinterBash
Stack Overflow sent to me 
Tim Post's head and R-E-S-P-E-C-T for hitting the rep cap

On the second day of WinterBash
Stack Overflow sent to me 
Two Marauders,
Tim Post's head and R-E-S-P-E-C-T for hitting the rep cap

On the third day of WinterBash
Stack Overflow sent to me 
Johnny Three-Hats,
Two Marauders,
Tim Post's head and R-E-S-P-E-C-T for hitting the rep cap

On the fourth day of WinterBash
Stack Overflow sent to me 
Four Archeologists,
Johnny Three-Hats,
Two Marauders,
Tim Post's head and R-E-S-P-E-C-T for hitting the rep cap

On the fifth day of WinterBash
Stack Overflow sent to me 
Five Defenders of the Realm,
Four Archeologists,
Johnny Three-Hats,
Two Marauders,
Tim Post's head and R-E-S-P-E-C-T for hitting the rep cap

On the sixth day of WinterBash
Stack Overflow sent to me 
Six RoboCops,
Five Defenders of the Realm,
Four Archeologists,
Johnny Three-Hats,
Two Marauders,
Tim Post's head and R-E-S-P-E-C-T for hitting the rep cap

On the seventh day of WinterBash
Stack Overflow sent to me 
Seven Frosties the Snowman,
Six RoboCops,
Five Defenders of the Realm,
Four Archeologists,
Johnny Three-Hats,
Two Marauders,
Tim Post's head and R-E-S-P-E-C-T for hitting the rep cap

On the eighth day of WinterBash
Stack Overflow sent to me 
Eight Lonesome Cowboys,
Seven Frosties the Snowman,
Six RoboCops,
Five Defenders of the Realm,
Four Archeologists,
Johnny Three-Hats,
Two Marauders,
Tim Post's head and R-E-S-P-E-C-T for hitting the rep cap

On the ninth day of WinterBash
Stack Overflow sent to me 
Nine Sock Puppets,
Eight Lonesome Cowboys,
Seven Frosties the Snowman,
Six RoboCops,
Five Defenders of the Realm,
Four Archeologists,
Johnny Three-Hats,
Two Marauders,
Tim Post's head and R-E-S-P-E-C-T for hitting the rep cap

On the tenth day of WinterBash
Stack Overflow sent to me 
Ten Bounty Hunters,
Nine Sock Puppets,
Eight Lonesome Cowboys,
Seven Frosties the Snowman,
Six RoboCops,
Five Defenders of the Realm,
Four Archeologists,
Johnny Three-Hats,
Two Marauders,
Tim Post's head and R-E-S-P-E-C-T for hitting the rep cap

On the eleventh day of WinterBash
Stack Overflow sent to me 
Eleven Chuck Yeagers,
Ten Bounty Hunters,
Nine Sock Puppets,
Eight Lonesome Cowboys,
Seven Frosties the Snowman,
Six RoboCops,
Five Defenders of the Realm,
Four Archeologists,
Johnny Three-Hats,
Two Marauders,
Tim Post's head and R-E-S-P-E-C-T for hitting the rep cap

On the twelfth day of WinterBash
Stack Overflow sent to me 
Twelve Oh the Horrors,
Eleven Chuck Yeagers,
Ten Bounty Hunters,
Nine Sock Puppets,
Eight Lonesome Cowboys,
Seven Frosties the Snowman,
Six RoboCops,
Five Defenders of the Realm,
Four Archeologists,
Johnny Three-Hats,
Two Marauders,
Tim Post's head and R-E-S-P-E-C-T for hitting the rep cap

Comment: I had to shorten this a lot to meet the character limit.

Comment: bluefeet, this is only about one third of the maximum length.  Compare it to the other answers.  If you have more please include it!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The full version is 3k characters, I had to cut it down. :(

Comment: Personally I'd like to read it. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard updated with both versions. :) Hopefully I won't get disqualified for the extended edition.

Comment: It sure reads better that way. hehe  I hope I don't get ya into trouble.

Answer (score 8):

A long day, reviewing gems from eras long passed. The slave traders called Stack Exchange force us to review old questions. They promise us Careers when we leave... none have yet left.

Hats are our reward. We first earn the hat called "Passed Judgement." Given to new inductees on their first day. To serve as a reminder of all our delinquent pasts.

Those lucky few of us who... survive... are rewarded with the hat they call "Mr. Peanut Monopoly McDuck." For our persistence and survival, I think. The name is a joke. I laughed.

They gave me a gold badge with the hat. I know I will never have a chance to spend it. Over 100,000 left to go, and then we will be free. One of these days, the stack will overflow. Then, maybe, we can climb to freedom.

Some of us have gone mad. Tim Post, well... we all love Tim Post. But he's a little touched in the head. Sits and yodels all day. They will dispose of him, soon, but at least he makes us a little happier. He reminds us that there is some respite in insanity, after all.

Comment: 1024 character limit...

Comment: @fredley Aw, crap :( I'll see what I can do...

Comment: Yeah, I only read that after my first draft was nearly 2000...

Comment: Whoo. Edited. 1024 chars exactly.

Comment: Nope. It is 1023. You have one character left. Unless I counted wrong. :-D

Comment: @qwerty so it would seem! :D

Comment: Do you count one or two for \n? :)

Answer (score 8):

♫*Ohhhhhhhhh*
♫

I went to Stack Overflow to find some brand new *hats*
I found a Sock Puppet and a big Link to the *Past*
I earned my Silver Badge and bit it to make *sure*
I never met Tim Post or his head so *pure*
I have heard that his yodeling can be *heard*
I hear that he might even grow to be a *bard*

I think all of my *rhyming* is done for *now*
I believe that this might in the end just earn me a *cow*

Comment: `heard` doesn't rhyme with `beard` unless you have a really weird accent BTW.

Comment: Yea.... I _tried_.... Do you know any better words @Malachi ?

Comment: leered?  steered? neared? ... doesn't really fit the context but...

Comment: None of those rhyme with `heard` :-P

Comment: my bad, I was rhyming the wrong word.  how about herd, as in herd of buffalo.

Comment: try this, http://www.rhymezone.com/r/rhyme.cgi?Word=heard&typeofrhyme=perfect&org1=syl  Nerd would be perfect.

Comment: Makes no sense with the word `nerd` :-( Sorry. Thank you for trying though :-D

Comment: how about change the words on that line and use the word absurd? yodeling always seems absurd to me

Comment: Ok I changed that line a bit @Malachi

Answer (score 8):

*To the tune of Jingle-Bells*

```
Ohhhhh Dashing through the posts!
With more downvotes on the way!
Over to Meta I go! 
To write about my day! (ha ha ha) 

Hats are SE bling
Making regulars fight! 
what fun it is to double ping,
on the chat system all night!

OHHHHHHHHHHHHH

Stack Overflow, Stack Overflow, 
Why doesn't this site pay?
Oh! what fun it is to argue
about why jQuery sucks all day!

Oh! Stack Overflow, Stack Overflow, 
You just made my day!
I could be working but instead I am 
Writing meta posts this way (in a song!)
```

Comment: **RULE BREAKER**! :-P

Comment: I suppose I will not win then. maybe I'll start a meta post asking why... hrm...

Comment: That will be the day @rlemon That will be the day...

Comment: I'm going to regret this, but why on earth would people say jQuery sucks?

Comment: well peek around at the jQuery tag newest questions... 9/10 are hideous :P so really that should be 'it isn't jQuery, but the people who abuse it' however that didn't rhyme as well.

Comment: jQuery sucks? WHAT?!? You should drop that and just use jQuery instead.

Answer (score 8):

### Tim Post's Head and the Unicorns

<sup>([One of Atwood's fables](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Ants_and_the_Grasshopper))</sup>

In Meta Stack Overflow one summer's day, Tim Post's Head was hopping about, chirping and yodeling to its <s>heart's</s> brain's content. A Unicorn passed by, bearing along with great toil an Old Hat it was taking to the nest.

*"Why not come and be Chatty Chatty,"* said Tim Post's Head, *"Instead of toiling and moiling in that way?"*

*"I am helping to lay up hats because Winter is Coming,"* said the Unicorn, *"and recommend you do the same."*

*"Why bother about winter?"* said Tim Post's head; *"we have got plenty of hats at present."* But the Unicorn went on its way and continued its toil. When Winterbash came Tim Post's Head had no hats and found itself freezing to death, while it saw the Unicorns wearing The Millner because of their hard work in gathering 20 hats. Then Tim Post's Head knew:

**When your head is all you have left, it's best to worry about getting hats.**

Comment: 913 characters, including spaces, excluding markup

Answer (score 7):

**Area 51**: the final frontier. These are the sites of the network *Stack Exchange*. Its **42**-year mission: to explore strange new ways to say “**Hello World!**”, to seek out new answers and **steal checkmarks**, to be the **First** to boldly **yodel** where no one has yodeled before.

Answer (score 6):

Bounties on questions and checkmarks on answers
Bright red Sock Puppets and scary Bounty Hunters
The winter bash icon lit up with earnings
These are a few of my favorite things

Teal colored unicorns and sharp witty comments
Yodels and rainbows and multi colliders with contents
Stack Overflow users with rep caps in their stockings
These are a few of my favorite things

Gravatars dressed in old hats with 8 bit pixels
Hats that stay on my signatures and profiles
Silver badged users who are now yearlings
These are a few of my favorite things

Comment: [♫](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=33o32C0ogVM), [Favorite Things lyrics](http://www.stlyrics.com/lyrics/thesoundofmusic/myfavoritethings.htm)

Answer (score 5):

### Mr. Binx and the Shog

<sup>([One of Atwood's fables](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Hare_and_the_Tortoise_(Aesop)))</sup>

Mr. Binx was once boasting of his review speed before the developers in the Tavern on the Meta. *"I have never yet been beaten,"* said he, *"when I put forth my full speed I can outrace Chuck Yeager. I challenge any one here to review with me."*

The Shog said quietly, *"I accept your challenge."*

*"Ho Ho Ho, that is a good joke,"* said Mr. Binx; *"I could reach the review cap before you yodel Hello World!"*

*"Keep your boasting till you've beaten,"* answered the Shog. *"Shall we race?"*

So a review limit was fixed and a start was made. Mr. Binx created a noticeable dent in the close vote reviews queue at once, but soon stopped and, to show his contempt for the Shog, went to steal a checkmark. The Shog plodded on and plodded on, and when Mr. Binx had his Marauder Hat, he saw the Shog just near the review limit and could not review in time to save the race. Then said the Shog:

> *"You should have used JQuery."*

Answer (score 5):

### The Cat-Maiden

<sup>([One of Atwood's fables](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Cat_and_Venus))</sup>

The devs were once disputing on [Philosophy.SE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/) whether it was possible for a living being to change its nature. Joel said *"Yes,"* but Jeff said *"No."* So, to try The Question, Jupiter turned a Cat into a Community Manager, and gave her to the Yodeling Public Beta as a mod. The Public Beta began and the Cat-Maiden sat down at the keyboard taking care of 15 helpful flags. *"See,"* said Joel, to Jeff, *"how mod-like she behaves. Who could tell that yesterday she was but a Cat? Surely her nature is changed?"*

*"Wait a minute,"* replied Jeff, and made a Sock Puppet posing as a mouse post to the Public Beta. No sooner did Anna Lear see this than [she jumped up from her seat and took a mouthful of monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeovV.jpg). *"Ah, you see,"* said Jeff,

*"Nature wins out."*

Comment: [True story](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XeovV.jpg).

Comment: @Anna, who says parables don't have any real world applications?

Answer (score 4):

To the tune of .. aww you'll get it :D

```
On the nth day of christmas Stack Overflow gave to me..
12 Syntax Errors
11 Downvotes
10 Low Quality Posts
9 Bad Questions
8 Answer Flags
7 Rollbacks
6 Chatroom Stars
FIVE GOLDEN HATSSSS
4 jQuery rulez
3 There's a plugin for that
2 relevant tags
AND A TIM POST YODELING IN A NODE TREEEEEE
```

Comment: You did not follow the rules! :-P

Comment: since when does anyone on meta follow *rules* ??

Answer (score 4):

```
The answer to chess?!
"First" rep cap hit, Yodeling!
Award a bounty~?
```

Comment: Answer is in [HAIKU](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/style-and-usage/rules-for-writing-haiku.html)

Comment: Psst, change the first three words to "The Question on" - same number of syllables and you get the necessary second hat reference.

Answer (score 3):

First think about "[The Christmas Song" by Nat King Cole](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SOszvL9lgSs) - then read.

```
Questions on meta are all satire,
Moderators locking down your post
Newbie Complaints: "Why is my question closed?"
and hats that look like eskimos
Every regular knows, the close vote queue will never die
100 thousand votes, on the rise.
Tiny Tim, with his questions that show
we need to light the warehouse at night. 

We know that Hats are on their way
We only get them for the holiday
and every sockpuppet account is going to try
to get the kitty hat, two stars, or i'll die

And so I'm offering this 50pt bounty
to users from 1k to 92k
Although it's been said, many times, many ways .... 
how do I return an ajax result for you...
```

Comment: Cannot upvote due to lack of yodeling and/or tim's disembodied head. Well, I'm sure I can, but the power of Tim compels me not to.

Answer (score 3):

> 01010100011010000110100101110011001000000110100101110011001000000110000100100000010000110110100001110010011010010111001101110100011011010110000101110011001000000111010001100001011011000110010100101100000011010000101001001001011011100010000001110111011010000110100101100011011010000010000001110100011101110110111100100000011010000110000101110100011100110010000001110100011000010110101101100101001000000111000001100001011100100111010000100000011100000111001001101111011101010110010001101100011110010010111000001101000010100101010101110011011001010111001001110011001000000110101101101110011011110111011101110011001000000110000101101110011001000010000001100011011000010110111000100000011101110110010101101100011011000010000001110100011001010110110001101100001011000000110100001010010101000110100001101001011100110010000001100011011011110110110101110000011010010110110001100101011001000010000001101000011011110110110001101001011001000110000101111001001000000111010001100001011011000110010100101110

Comment: `011001000111010101101000101110101000010100`?

Comment: @qwertynl 42 / 8 = 5.25. This message means nothing it's just random 0's and 1's ?

Comment: Sorry I added extra bits there....

Comment: `011001000111010101101000`!

Comment: @qwertynl haha makes more sense now ^_^

Comment: `010010010010000001100100011010010110010000100000011011100110111101110100001000000111001001100101011000010110110001101001011110100110010100100000011010010111010000100000011101000110100001100001011101000010000001110111011001010010000001101000011000010110010000100000011101000110111100100000 01100100011001010110001101101111011011010111000001101001011011000110010100100000011110010110111101110101011100100010000001110000011011110111001101110100001000000110111101110010011010010110011101101001011011100110000101101100011011000111100100101110` @insertcleverxmasname

Comment: 001010101100012

Comment: I am tempted to flag this post because those look like some naughty bits

Answer (score 3):

Painfully
slogging
through
the mire
of the **Stack Overflow** close votes queue (already  having **performed

5 reviews in 5 queues** to achieve a shiny **RoboCop** <strike>mask</strike> hat*), I
chanced upon this very Meta post.  Due to my severest lack  of other
hats, and my agonizing envy of the mysterious **Eureka** hat, I availed
myself of this opportunity to try to gain *physical Stack Exchange stuff*,
in place of glorious digital headwear. Gazing upon the other entries, I
see that my chances are nil.  so I've decided to make this post in a shape
vaguely similar to that of a top hat, clinging to the meagerest of hopes
that **Tim Post's mug-addled head** will find some strange humo(u)r in
the rambling
of this humble
story I have
now written

---

A story of (hat-related) poverty

A story of (review-queue-related) pain

A story of (SE-swag-related) hope.

---

<sub>Brown.</sub>

---

*Seriously, that's not a hat.  Not even a little.

Comment: You are so weird, man.

Answer (score 3):

*In the spirit  of a totally pointless discussion I had yesterday*

Once upon a time, in the kingdom of Meta, there were two Tims.

Both were well renowned throughout the nation and R-E-S-P-E-C-Ted by all. Both had the ability to earn gold badges in a snap. One of them went on to be the greatest scholar of the nation, knowing every nook and cranny and secret passage. One became the foremost lawmaker, Keeper of the Swag, and ambassador to many nations like the land of Pets.

But everyone always wondered, who was *The* Tim? Who was greater?

To settle this they decided to have a duel, Fastest Gun In The West style. The first to answer wins.

On the appointed date both arrived and started writing. The scholar, always curious, looked to the side and... OH THE HORROR... noticed that his counterpart was a floating head.  This meant that  Tim the lawmaker had ascended to the level of Shog!

Eeeeek!, he cried, and realized that he could not hope to compete with such a being. He conceded defeat, and Tim the Lawmaker was henceforth known as The Tim.

*Hopefully the bad attempt at flattery works :p*

Comment: +1 for adding shog in the scenario hahah

Answer (score 3):

**Based on *Hershel and the Hannukah Goblins***:

One night, in the height of winterbash, an old man named Hershel arrived in the small town of StackOverflow. Looking around, he was astounded to see a complete lack of hats. When asked why, the town's users explained that an evil army of trolls had cursed SO; to restore the hats, Hershel would need to face the trolls by spending 8 nights in the review queues while wearing a hat.

Donning his festive **L'chaim** hat, Hershel entered the queues. The first night passed calmly - mostly grammar fixes and re-tags, quickly earning Hershel the **Florence Nightengale hat**.

The next nights progressed from benign not-actual-answers, to blatant requests for homework solutions, to, on the last night, a string of highly offensive comments. With a yodelling cry, Hershel flagged posts as fast as he could (he had long since earned **Conspiracy Theorist**). In desperation, he changed his avatar to the concussed and disembodied head of Tom Post. The trolls were terrified and left immediately.

Answer (score 3):

One day, Tim Post decided he wanted a [Red Ryder carbine-action 200-shot range model BB rifle with a compass in the stock](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085334/?ref_=nv_sr_1) for Winterbash instead of hats.

He asked the Bounty Hunter on Stack Overflow to win it for him.

Unfortunately for Tiny Tim, Florence Nightingale, told him he couldn’t have it because *"You'll shoot your eye out"*.

Knowing that Winter is Coming, he deeply wanted to be the Defender of the Realm, he convinced Frosty the Snowman that he was worthy of the Red Ryder rifle.  Tim yodeled with excitement, the noise caused an icicle to fall hitting his head giving him a concussion.

Florence screamed “Oh The Horror” but the Lonesome Cowboy rode in to save the day showing his silver badge while yelling “Hi Ho Silver” away.

Tim was not speedy like Chuck Yeager and would forever be a marauder wearing a patch over his eye.

The End.

Answer (score 2):

In a hole in the Ground there lived **Tim Post a' Yodeling**. Not a nasty, dirty, wet hole, filled with the ends of **Sock Puppets** and an oozy smell, nor yet a dry, bare hole with no **questions to close**. It was **Meta StackOverflow**, and that means **O the Horror**!

Answer (score 2):

[<sup>♫ **To the tune of Ylvis' "The Fox (What Does The Fox Say?)"** ♫</sup>](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jofNR_WkoCE)

---

*R-E-S-P-E-C-T* for *rep cap*

*Do The Swim!* for *5 reviews*

*Sock Puppet* when you *answer your own question*

and *Old Hat* for *early user*

*Upboated* for *5 posts scored 2*

*The Stallman* for *edit a cw post*

and the *Robocop* for *5 reviews in 5 queues*

*First!* for *starred chat on NYD*

and *The Milliner* for *20 hats*

and *Oh the Horror* for *guru badge on meta*

But there's one question

*StackOverflow* does not know

**WHY IS TIM YODELING?**

Ring-ding-ding-ding-dingeringeding!

Gering-ding-ding-ding-dingeringeding!

Gering-ding-ding-ding-dingeringeding!

**WHY IS TIM YODELING?**

Wa-pa-pa-pa-pa-pa-pow!

Wa-pa-pa-pa-pa-pa-pow!

Wa-pa-pa-pa-pa-pa-pow!

**WHY IS TIM YODELING?**

Hatee-hatee-hatee-ho!

Hatee-hatee-hatee-ho!

Hatee-hatee-hatee-ho!

**WHY IS TIM YODELING?**

Joff-tchoff-tchoff-tchoffo-tchoffo-tchoff!

Joff-tchoff-tchoff-tchoffo-tchoffo-tchoff!

Joff-tchoff-tchoff-tchoffo-tchoffo-tchoff!

**WHY IS TIM YODELING?**

Comment: One too many syllables on the chorus

Comment: "What does the fox say?" = 5 syllables, "Why is Tim Yodeling" = 6 syllables (yo-de-ling), you can cut one out with "why is" to "why's" or "yo-de-ling" to "yode'ling" without the emphasis on the "de". However, it would make far more sense as, "What's Tim Yodeling?" or "What is Tim Yode'ling?" or even "What does Tim Yodel?"

Comment: AmericanLuke and @jmac - The 1 syllable difference doesn't change anything. If you notice, there are 6 beats in that chorus line. Before "Say" is said, it pauses for a beat. It goes: **Beat 1** WHAT **Beat 2** DOES **Beat 3** THE **Beat 4** FOX **Beat 5** _pause_  **Beat 6** SAY?  Now, in my parody, instead of pausing, we fill Beat 5 as follows: **Beat 1** WHY **Beat 2** IS **Beat 3** TIM **Beat 4** YO **Beat 5** DE **Beat 6** LING? See how that works?

Comment: 1-and-2-and-3-and-4-and.  But yes, it does work.

Answer (score 2):

Deck the Halls with boughs of holly, Fa la la la la, la la la la.

Tis' the season to be jolly, **Ho ho ho** ho ho, ho ho ho ho.

Don we now our gay **Milliners**, Fa la la, la la la, la la la.

<kbd>Troll</kbd> the ancient moderators, Fa la la la la, la la la la.

**Get a third hat**, **Johnny three-hats**, Fa la la la la, la la la la.

Strike the harp and join the **Yodel**, Fa la la la la, la la la la.

Follow me to **Stack Overflow**, Fa la la, la la la, la la la.

> While I tell of Secret hats, O', Fa la la, la la la, la la la.

Answer (score 2):

[image: On Stack Overflow,<br>Hunting robo-reviewers.<br>I am Robocop<br><br>5 reviews a day?<br>Try 200, all approved.<br>Make it Rain on them.<br><br>Tim's head injury<br>Was not caused by falling hats.<br>It was them, I'm sure.<br>]

Answer (score 2):

### The nightmare before Christmas

> There must be a mixup I thought to myself. 
> It can't be right. Maybe that shelf 
> with the box that struck Tim Post in the head 
> did much damage to StackExchange servers instead?
>
> "Oh the Horror" cried users of StackOverflow. 
> How could this happen?  Does anyone know? 
> The Question that haunts is about the elite. 
> How could one earn more rep this year than Jon Skeet?
>
> Win a bounty?  win 10?  win a million? 
> You need to win more than that (try a billion). 
> Ninja skills, (shurikens) and speedy suggestions 
> come from Martijn Pieters' answers to python based questions.
>
> At least there are hats to collect the most of. 
> That would be a great accomplishment to boast of.
> But no, Martijn's got the lead in that too. 
> It looks like my nightmares just might all be true.
>
> They can't be true! -- I'll wake in the morn
> And the dream will be over, no longer forlorn.
> I'll open my laptop and as always has been 
> I'll see the leaderboard set right once again.

Answer (score 1):

I entered a dirty old corner club. I was a lonesome cowboy carrying my hard-earned silver badge with pride. I walked up to the bar and asked for a drink, but before the bartender could react, a mysterious figure loudly entered the club. I only saw a shadow until they stepped out of the dark. There he was. Mr. Binx was yodeling on Tim Post's head. Photography skills would have been useful that day. That was definitely the first and last time I'm going to see that.

Answer (score 1):

```
much story              cat hat!

           wow


                   very updo

many Tim              
                much yodeling

wow!
```

But seriously, a holiday rhyme:

```
Cruising around town in my new cat hat
Looking for a stack question that isn't crap
Tim Post yodeling but that ain't wack
He does it on the daily till his rep hit the cap

A downvote killed his updo
There was nothing that he could do
When he editted his post the voter put him a stew
And that was so impromptu
```

- SO Rap

Comment: such attempt. so meme. very try.

Comment: @Anna Lear wow!

Answer (score 1):

I was sitting on the couch playing The Legend Of Zelda: **A Link To The Past** and **yodelling** along to the latest Jewel song, when suddenly there was a knock on my door.  It was **Johnny Three-Hats**, looking to collect for his paper route.  "Two dollars!", he said.  I looked him dead in the eye and replied, "What's that gonna do for you, **earn a silver badge** or something?  Go try your luck at **Aviation**."  It wasn't until many years later that I found out his real name was Jon Skeet...

Comment: Where is Tim Post's head?

Comment: "or yodelling", it said.

Comment: Hmmmm I just understood it to be both :-P

Comment: @qwertynl that's not how "or" works ;)

Comment: I was never any good and ands are ors.... @Laura :-P

Answer (score 1):

One dark night, the night that Hats were turned on, a user was poking around the dev.so site. "A hole!" he cried, his smile quite broad, "I got in! I can see they post crap!" He was right - the devs do post crap to test stuff.

He poked around the site, looking at users. He found Tim Post, with his head as an avatar. In the recent questions, the user could see plainly that Tim was creative with titles. "Asdfjkspammydespam!" sang one. "This better work" cried another.

The user tracked down Oded in the Tavern, and whispered quite softly, "I got in to the dev site!" Oded replied, code at the ready, "I see your point! How? We did lock it up quite nicely!" I *`<censored>`*, and it let me in. I even did 5 reviews! Quick, fix the bug before others find the way in!

Oded fixed the bug, but the user still had cookies. The cookies let him in, and Oded couldn't kick him back out. "Clear your cookies," said the almighty dev, "or else I shall have to destroy you, like we do on Stack Overflow!" "Nay," said the user, for he wanted to know how it felt to be destroyed. "Fine, then!" said the dev, pushing the button that caused the user to go *poof!*

The user is no longer there, and stays away to this day. He stays in the public sites, with no sock puppets to see.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see where this meets the questions specifications.. You're missing a hat or two.

Comment: @Seth "I See Your Point" and "Sock Puppet".

Answer (score 1):

*A few weeks had passed since the great opening.*

Metaville is no exception as a community and, as in all communities, everybody had to take a look; the regulars, the foreigners and the newcomers. This place was magnificent and for the first time of year, all the inhabitants forgot their worries about the endless queue of tasks that they could not seem to get rid of and they all enjoyed talking about this great new shop that opened it's doors. Some were trying to peek in the back store to see what merchandise was secretly kept in stock. All buyers were wearing proudly their new acquisitions by placing them on various position so it fits best their portrait.

The Metaville hat store had finally opened it's doors and you could feel the joy that it brought to all it's customers.

I remember seeing the community's elder Mr.Skeet proudly wearing a hat that made me think of Chuck Yeager. I even saw the village's wizard putting a transformers mask on his child's face. Aww.. I wish this would never stop.

Answer (score 1):

Winter is coming
[Others](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/White_Walkers) Reanimated
A head rolls free, Tim?

Game of Thrones, oh no!
Close or delete, pass judgement
It's Stack Overflow

Comment: Y U NO FOLLOW RULES?

Comment: Could you explain why? It's funny to me, but I'm strange like that...

Comment: Read the objective.

Comment: Now I've done that can you explain what this misses?

Comment: I am not sure... now I am just confusing myself...

Comment: :-), fairly sure I got everything, save funny to some people, but I've been warped by the things I mention...

Comment: ****GHOOOOST EDIT****

Answer (score 1):

On this day did a mother reserved and most prim,
Worried about her son, tell herself “Do the Swim!”
She registered on Parenting,
And asked about his yodeling.
Is it kosher? Upvoted but closed. L'chaim!

Answer (score 1):

On a cold exception throwing Christmas Eve on mSO Shog9 said to himslef, "a time for finding yourself a year older, and not a hat richer". One debugger over sat balpha, busily making more hats for users.

That night Shog9 was visited by his Sock Puppet who had been banned and wanted to save Shog9 from the same fate, "3 languages will visit you tonight so that you may answer your own question", it said.

He later awakens to Java, the Ghost of Christmas Past, who shows him the memory leaks they used to share, and then all the hats of his past such as Monarch by Right.

He then reflects to C#, the Ghost of Christmas Present, who shows Tiny Tim yodeling while being hit in the head with a mug, and balpha working hard to make everyone's hats perfect.

Mathing a pattern, F#, the Ghost of Christmas Yet, shows a gravatar with no hat. Shog9 realizes it is his gravatar! Suddenly he finds himself back at his debugger.

Overwhelmed by the chance to earn more hats, he immediately starts a bounty and posts on Christmas. Ho Ho Ho!

Comment: So I take it the downvoter didn't like my Christmas Carol reference?

Answer (score 1):

I have a dog, his name is Chuck. He runs so fast that I often call him Chuck Yeager.
We run together, eat together, answer Stack Overflow questions together... he is a great programmer.

One day in early December he sits on my lap, helping me hunt down a really nasty bug.
All of a sudden my dear Chuck disappears into thin air, leaving behind even his precious mug.

I called my friend Mulder who confirmed to me, "yes your dog was abducted and is now on my shoulder".

Packing my things I raced to Nevada, just to be told "dude we are sorry, but Chuck died of cold".

Not giving up I hired a Necromancer, and for meager $1,000,000 he Reanimated my Chuck back to life. 
Oh then Tim Post's head came floating into view,  then boomed: "I know what you did on December 5<sup>th</sup>!"

"Sorry I downvoted you oh Tim, please don't take my Chuck again!"

The head poofed away in a pink smoke, Chuck and I got back home in the speed of a rocket.
Sitting together again we finally solved the bug: as always, it was just a missing curly bracket.

Answer (score 1):

**Ode to <strike>Bacon</strike> Stack Overflow**

A low-rep meta user ate some bad bacon

and that trichinosis sure had him shakin'

but he still made a post

so give him a toast

'cause after bad bacon was swallowed

the rules were all followed.

Now let those who are curious

enjoy an answer that's spurious

though they may need a hint, or a jsfiddle

for his lame holiday code riddle.

So stare for a bit and you may see what I mean

that perhaps this post is more than it seems.

Indeed it's true, a coder's delight

As they could verify, my source is right.

Tho if no one can get it,

Then it may need an edit!

Comment: Did.. you read the question?

Comment: Yes. Look harder, you'll see it!

Comment: :/ why downvote? I guess u didn't find how I followed the rules!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but maybe you should clarify your answer 'cause if so many people can't get it that's bad.

Comment: @Seth bah it's fine. Bad riddle I suppose (or maybe really good!). Tho I guess a small hint would help (added).  Perhaps one person will get it! If they do, let me know.

Comment: I think it's a nice rhythm, but doesn't belong in this particular contest. Lasts years would have been perfect though

Comment: @Seth well it's a short, humorous(slightly), fictional story. I didn't really eat bad bacon. I just had regular bacon. So I think it fits.

Answer (score 1):

### The Timawock

Twas brillig, and the slithy downvotes
  Did flow and gimble the question:
All mimsy were the OP's,
  mome and frumious, was uffish the OP.

Beware the Timawock, my son!
  The post locks that bite, the votes that close!
Beware the Flagflag bird, and shun
  The frumious OP!

He took his comment reply in hand:
  Long time the *MSO* foe he sought
So rested he by the whiffling reply,
  And stood awhile in thought.

And, as in uffish thought he stood,
  The Timawock, with eyes of flame,
Came whiffling through to snicker-snack,
  And burbled as it *edit a community wiki post*!

One, two! One, two! And through and through
  *With Great Power* slithy replies did came!
*Oh the Horror*, He left it dead,
  and with *Tim's head, he went yodelling back*.

And, has thou slain the Timawock?
  Come to my arms, my beamish boy!
O frabjous day! Callooh! Callay!
  He chortled in his joy.

---

---

---

For those of you completely bewildered, it's from the poem "[Jabberwocky](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/poem/171647)".

Translated words:

Timawock = Jabberwock
Jabberwock =  Large winged chimera with the body of a dragon, a whiskered, fish-like head, insectile antennae and a pair of talon-like hands on both its arms and its wings, which may also serve as forelegs when it walked on the ground
(No offence intended Tim..)

Brillig = Evening
Slithy = Smooth/active
Gimble = To bore holes
Mimsy = Miserable
Mome = Serious
Frumious = Combination of  fuming and furious
Uffish = A state of mind when the voice is gruffish, the manner is ruffish, and the temper huffish
Flagflag bird = Jubjub bird = Dangerous animal
Whiffling = Variable/evasive
Snicker-snack = To fight with knife
Burbled = Confused
Beamish = Bright
Frabjous = Combination of fabulous and joyous - wonderful

Comment: Great idea, but execution could use some work (the meter is all off from the original, you should have used jquery).

Comment: @jmac what could I have used jquery for?

Comment: the real question is what COULDN'T you have used jquery for!

Comment: Maybe it is for someone who uses jquery... I sincerely do not know what you are suggesting. What I wrote was just some fun, written in 15 mins at about 2am. And is just a take on the original poem which itself is a fantasy poem, full of made up words and nonsense gibberish. Not sure better "accuracy" or "execution" is something that can be done with it.

Comment: Sorry, that was probably a bit obtuse for non-regular meta users. See [the Many Memes of Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/209637) to understand the jquery comment. (no offense intended, I really love the poem, I just wanted a bit more, perhaps I set my expectations too high?)

Answer (score 1):

It was a bright cold day in December, and the review count read thirteen. Winston, ears tucked into his old hat to escape the cursed wind, swiftly flagged five of them to unlock the link to Stack Overflow. As he did, he could not suppress one recurring thought; winter is coming.

At the top of the page a bright banner, too wide for most screens, had been set to appear. It depicted simply an enormous head, more than 2000 pixels wide: the head of a man in his late thirties, with a crooked smile and a boater cocked jauntily on his brow. Winston made for the suggested edits. It was no use trying the close votes. Even at the best of times it was broken, and at present growing rapidly. It was an effect of the ongoing Winter Bash. The queue was three clicks away, and Winston went slowly, knuckles cracking twice along the way. On each page, at the top of the screen, the banner with the enormous head gazed. It was one of those images where the eyes seem to glitter. TIM POST IS WATCHING YOU, the caption beneath it ran.

Comment: Adapted from [1984](http://www.george-orwell.org/1984/0.html), 1024 characters.

Answer (score 1):

### Gilligan's Question

Just sit right back and you'll hear a tale, 
A tale of a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)  
That started from this great idea 
He typed it with some zest.

The question was a bit obtuse,  
Two downvotes and close votes. 
**Five users flagged the question** right then 
Three more close votes. Three more close votes.

The comments started getting rough,  
The OP’s ego was tossed,  
If not for the courage of the editors  
The question would be lost, the question would be lost.

The question was reviewed in a queue of this intrepid little site  
By **Tim Post’s Head**, 
Bill the Lizard too,  
**Mr. Peanut Monopoly McDuck** and Shog9,  
**A Sock Puppet**,  
**The Marauder** and Anna Lear,  
Here on **MetaStackOverflow**.

Answer (score 0):

So there I was, playing *Poker* with *Tim Post's yodeling Sock Puppet head*.  The yodeling kept pissing me off, yet I was still able to pull off a *Full House* to his king high, ending the game and allowing me to *Win a Bounty* of $1000 cash.  He got up, threw all the cards in the air and, like a *Marauder*, tried to attack me.  I grabbed his little sock puppet head, and told him that if he doesn't stop attacking me every time I beat his high hand, that I would put his head in a *Blender*.  He told me that it wouldn't work because *Physics* state that sock puppet heads cannot be blended, and I told him that that's the stupidest thing I've ever heard.  Needless to say, he disagreed with me, and assured me that his thinking is sound but a little muddled since *Winter is Coming*.  Perhaps I have *Passed Judgment* a little too quickly?  I don't think so.  He's just a sock puppet head.  They're all *Skeptics*.  After much *R-E-S-P-E-C-T*-ful dispute, we both eventually agreed to calm down, stop playing cards for a while, and just sit down and watch *Home Improvement*.

Answer (score 0):

I walked out onto the street, my head shaking.  I couldn't believe her question.  It was bad enough that of all the dark corners of the internet she could have wandered into, she had to log on to StackOverflow; the question, though, the question was just too much.

Then, when she answered her own question, and the Sock Puppet appeared on her head, my despair was complete.  Tim Post yodelling outside my window couldn't make it any worse.  My shame was posted for all to see, and I could not show my avatar in Stack Overflow any longer.

I knew answering that question with [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) was lazy, when it could be done with pure [css](/questions/tagged/css).  I never thought it would come back to haunt me like this...

Answer (score 0):

> **Hello, world!** A hat, at that.
>   **The question** will be asked! (A question that must never, ever be answered. <sup>[1](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Silence)</sup>)
>
> As poor Tim Post scratched his head,
> A Stack Overflow notification
>   stared at him in red.
>
> His question was closed, with one comment left:
> "Answer your own
>   question." So he replied with deft.
>
> Why did you close this, five of you fools!
> Why are you making up your
>   own crazy rules?
>
> The last to close the question sent a few thugs,
> and on Tim's poor
>   head, fell a pallet of mugs.

Answer (score 0):

Alice was dusting the fireplace when a mug-shaped ornament fell on her head and knocked her out. As she came to, a white rabbit dashed past, muttering: “I'm late! I need to deliver this message to Tim Post!” The rabbit dropped a piece of paper as he ran out. Alice read the paper:

> ERNQ ZR

“Odder and odder”, she thought. “What does it mean?” She decided to ask on Cryptography Stack Exchange. “I hope my question shan't remain unseen for a week, for I have to go to school.”

But the Duchess complained: “OH THE HORROR! THE QUESTION IS OFF-TOPIC! I HAVE PASSED JUDGEMENT: OFF WITH HER HEAD!”

The Milliner (for Alice had learned that he was such) and the Dormouse, who were Alice's good friends, objected: “Please, Your Highness, do not blame the messenger!”

The Duchess would not get off her high horse. “D-I-S-R-E-S-P-E-C-T! HEADS MUST ROLL! OFF WITH TIM POST'S HEAD!”

The Duchess reached across the site and started shaking Alice. “Alice? Are you all right?”, a friendlier voice said.

Answer (score 0):

Once upon a time, Robocop said "Hello, World!"

Tim Post's head yodelled "Robotics!".

Mr. Binx said "this is a secret hat".

They all lived happily ever after.

Answer (score -1):

[For sale: old hat, never worn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_sale:_baby_shoes,_never_worn)

Comment: It doesn't quite have the same tragic quality

Comment: @RichardTingle: http://i302.photobucket.com/albums/nn120/Golbleen/thatsthejoke.jpg