# Please reopen the Stack Exchange Store!

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, shop, t-shirt

I really would love to buy a StackOverflow T-Shirt, and I guess I'm not alone.

In the first I thought about to limit it so a reputation could to avoid a overrun to your shop, but I [read that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137580/171881) you *"only averaged maybe $20-$50 a day in sales"*. So this limit does not make sense. But it would be a great thing for getting more rep ;-)

I think it should be possible to create a simple wait list formula, where you could hoarding the orders and send the order out once in quarter. That would solve your logistic problems and possible lower your shipping costs.

I really have no problem to wait some month for one StackOverflow T-Shirt as long I would get one.

However I read that you also give them away on some special events. Do you have such events even in Europe? Might be also in Germany?

Comment: @TravisJ This seems to be a plea to reopen the store and references facts from the supposed duplicate. Hence I'm not sure it is a duplicate. But maybe it would be better as an answer to that question?

Comment: @rekire - we discussed that some time ago after a swag style giveaway done on SharePoint Overflow. In the end our idea was to print a replica of the original T-Shirt. Not the same, but since the original is no longer sold, I think that no one will get angry if you give the site some more visibility by wearing a replica ^_^

Comment: IMHO this is no dub because I know and referenced that question. I gave another aspect about the shop.

Comment: These ideas do nothing to address the huge overhead of maintaining tax info in every state and/or country we have an employee in.  This is a yearly thing, takes a ton of time/effort, and isn't affected much by the number of batches we process.

Comment: @rekire and anyone who really want a T-shirt: 10 users won shirts in the last Winter Bash events, see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212433/should-employees-with-head-injuries-be-allowed-to-post-on-meta) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213769/work-is-hard-lets-color-the-walls). The winners are listed there, try to contact them and ask if anyone is willing to sell his shirt. (only if they expose public contact info in their profile, or available in chat)

Comment: Seems like a duplicate to me. Pretty much confirmed by the fact that the accepted answer is little more than a link to the duplicate question.

Comment: I accepted it because basically some mods confined it. If a mod would answer I would accept that answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The Stack Exchange staff decided to discontinue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137579/what-happened-to-the-stack-exchange-store) the store for several reasons (cost, give an unique value for gifts given to people who are awesome as Michael Pryorfor said).
It also takes too much time for the amount of sales made.